# What does redefinition of unused 'on_message' mean

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

This bot that I am making on Discord is just a hangman game. I've been able to do the most basic part of the bot and now am trying to add a 2nd command. But there is an error on line 24 that pops up saying "redefinition of unused 'on_message' from line 13".

The 2nd command is supposed to print something once a person sends "$start". However, it does not work when I do so.

This is my current code:

```
import discord 
import random 
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
  .format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
   return

  if message.content.startswith("$help"):
    await message.channel.send("To start your game, type '$start'")


client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith("$start"):
    await message.channel.send("You will have to guess a month. Have fun :) (The first letter will be always capital)")
```

This is where the problem lies:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message): #this is line 24
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith("$start"): 
    await message.channel.send("You will have to guess a month. Have fun :) (The first letter will be always capital)")
```

Comment: You are defining a function called `on_message` twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**:
You have redefined the `on_message` function. This means, there are 2 functions with the same name `on_message`.

**Solution**:
Since you have been using some `if` statements to decide which function to execute on which command, you can group all `if` statements into one function, so your code would look like:

```
import discord 
import random 
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
   return

  if message.content.startswith("$help"):
    await message.channel.send("To start your game, type '$start'") 

  if message.content.startswith("$start"):
    await message.channel.send("You will have to guess a month. Have fun :) (The first letter will be always capital)")

client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states what it means literally: you are redefining the `on_message` event for the same `Client`.

Typically you would use the `commands.Bot` client from *discord.ext* branch instead of the native `Client` when implementing bots with commands.

So this piece of code:

```
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
     return

  if message.content.startswith("$help"):
    await message.channel.send("To start your game, type '$start'")
```

would be replaced with this:

```
client = commands.Bot("$")
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
  if ctx.author == client.user:
     return
  await message.channel.send("To start your game, type '$start'")
```

However FYI, you can have multiple `on_message` listeners in your code through the `Bot.listen()` decorator.